# Importing a video in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am reading at [working with video](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-video/)

```
import React from "react"
import DogVideo from "../assets/dog.mp4"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <video controls>
      <source src={DogVideo} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
}
```

However I am trying something similar `import background from "../../static/assets/vid/michaelpr.mp4"` but I get an error

Cannot find module '../../static/assets/vid/michaelpr.mp4' or its corresponding type definition ts(2307).

What am I doing wrong? Yes, the file is there. I have a CSS file that I am importing from the static folder without any problem.

Comment: I know you say that the file is there, but I curious to know: would it work if you bumped the file up from the "Vid" folder to the "assets" folder? It might be a Gatsby specific shortcut to read from the "Assets" folder in particular, and it might not work with nested folders. Otherwise just be sure you are counting the double-dots on the root-pathing correctly. It is also possible that you might not be able to use the import syntax rather than "Require" as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837024/load-local-mp4-file-as-source-for-video-tag-in-react-gatsby-website

Comment: It seems that this is only an error that is displayed in Visual Studio Code. I finally said to heck with it and started to work on something else and i noticed despite with Visual Studio Code indicated the video appeared on the web site. I am not sure the problem with Visual Studio Code.